# C pointers and following functions

Tags: c

1)

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof (*ptr));
```

In regard to `sizeof(*ptr)`, `*ptr` is deferencing `ptr` - it is the value pointed to by `ptr`?  Then is `sizeof(*ptr)` equal to the total memory size pointed to by `ptr`?

2)

```
void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{ 
  char *message;
  message = (char *) ptr;
  printf("%s \n", message);
}
```

Question2,  `void*  print_message_function` expects a return type of `void*`  or something but the function below didn't return anything.

Comment: The general rule here is one question per post, so that it's clear what the question is and an answer can be accepted. If you ask more than one question, multiple people can each answer just one of them, meaning that it's impossible to choose a correct answer. (In this case, someone could correctly answer #1 and someone else correctly answer #2. Which one would be "right"?)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask yourself what the variable `*ptr` is? Hint, it's on the first line.
2. That's not actually a question. But, if you're asking if it's wrong, then not really. However, you'll probably get into trouble if you try to *use* the return value.

Interestingly, the standard still allows not returning an explicit value from a function clearly intended to return one. Clause `6.8.6.4 The return statement /1` of `C11` states:

> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is void. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
>   whose return type is void.

This only states where a particular form of the `return` statement may *not* be. It does not state that an explicit `return` statement must exist in a non-void function.

Answer (score 0):

> Question1, sizeof(*ptr), *ptr=the deferencing, the value pointed by
>   ptr?

No. By the ptr itself. e.g., `int x = 123,*ptr = &x;`  `*x =` the address of `123` in memory.

> sizeof(*ptr)=total memory size pointed by the ptr?

It's the size of an pointer,that's just an integer value; i.e, an `int`. Therefore,the size of an andress is `sizeof(int)`.

> Question2, void* print_message_function expects a return type of void*
>   or something but the function below didn't return anything.

Why do this? I don't know exactly what the C std says about this,but the caller probably will access garbage value. Don't make confusing between `void` and `void*` they are very different.

Comment: `sizeof(*ptr)` isn't the size of an address, it's the size of `*ptr`, which is an `int`.  It'll be the same as `sizeof(int)` *anywhere*.

Comment: @caf: by address I wanted to mean integer. Fixed to me more clear

Comment: I'm sure what he means is that `*ptr` is an `int`, thus `sizeof *ptr` is `sizeof (int)`. Pointers aren't integer values (and they especially aren't `int`s). If they were, you'd be able to multiply pointers. The size of a pointer isn't required to be equal to the size of *any* integer.

Comment: You may also wish to consider the following quotes from [c-faq.com](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html): "*Depending on the "memory model" in use, 8086-family processors (PC compatibles) may use 16-bit data pointers and 32-bit function pointers, or vice versa.*" "*Older, word-addressed Prime machines were also notorious for requiring larger byte pointers (`char *`'s) than word pointers (`int *`'s).*" "*The Symbolics Lisp Machine, a tagged architecture, does not even have conventional numeric pointers; it uses the pair `<NIL, 0>` as a C null pointer.*"

Answer (score -1):

1. Any sizeof() is a compile time constant. If compiler couldn't determine it's value - it will be compile time error. Dereferencing is not an option.
2. No question asked. Regardless - it's bad, it should issue a compiler warning, and it will be really bad if someone will try to use this return value.

Comment: `void exception_to_point_1(size_t size) { char array[size]; printf("sizeof array: %zu\n", sizeof array); }`

Comment: That's weird. Never imagined VLA to affect it that way. Thanks.

Comment: No, i don't see a point of it. Why? I mean, if some particular implementation works some way or another - what's the matter, unless it breaks the rules? Either way, could (worse - should?) it be relied upon?

Comment: Well, Ch is an example of a valid C implementation that doesn't have a "compile time". Your second question is rhetorical. Yes, it should be relied upon that a valid C implementation follows the rules of valid C implementations. If it doesn't, then it's the fault of the people who wrote the C implementation, rather than the fault of the people who used the C implementation when something *really bad* goes wrong (eg. people getting lost at sea because their GPS doesn't work properly).

Comment: Well, maybe. Even perl have compile time, tho. I'm almost sure Ch have something like VM bytecode compiler - at least to improve performance, if not to check errors. But your GPS example is so good - no, anyway, you win :-D

Comment: Don't confuse implementation with specification. Most implementations of C are compilers, but that doesn't mean the language requires it.